# Impute missing date (YYYY-WW)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below and I need to insert rows where date is missing or omitted (Note this is weekly date):

```
A           B         C
'alpha'    2006-01    12
'beta'     2006-02    4
'kappa'    2006-04    2
```

Required result is something like:

```
A           B         C
'alpha'    2006-01    12
'beta'     2006-02    4
'gamma'    2006-03    0
'kappa'    2006-04    2
```

Can it be done?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where `gamma` comes from..

Comment: @QuangHoang Even 'alpha' or value above works

Answer (score 3):

Create an index based on `YYYY-WW` format using [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to weekly and fix `NaN` values. Here is a useful link to python [`strftimes`](https://strftime.org/)

```
# Set index to datetime - based on yyyy-ww format (the '-1' makes weeks start Monday)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['B'] + '-1', format='%Y-%W-%w')

# Resample to weekly - Monday start
df_new = df.resample('W-MON').first().fillna(0)

# Correct format of 'B' column back to yyyy-ww
df_new['B'] = df_new.index.strftime('%Y-%W')

# Optional step to reset index
df_new.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(df_new)
```

[out]

```
         A        B     C
0  'alpha'  2006-01  12.0
1   'beta'  2006-02   4.0
2        0  2006-03   0.0
3  'kappa'  2006-04   2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but throwing this error:  ValueError: 'G' is a bad directive in format '%G-%V-%u'

Comment: I've tested using pandas Version `'0.25.3'`  ... what version are you using?

Comment: alternatively try `format="%Y-%W-%w"`..? - I'll update my answer

Comment: thanks it works, but there is error like after 2016-52 it should give next missing as 2017-01 rather than 2016-01

Comment: I'm not able to replicate that error, I get imputing from `2016-52` to `2017-01` when I test. Can you add some more data?

Comment: Also it is omitting 'beta' values as it is resampling for 'alpha' values only .

Answer (score 1):

User resample() with an adequate filling function. Update:

```
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])
df = df.set_index('B').resample('1D').asfreq().reset_index()
```

Then you can refill NA's for every particular column personally.

Comment: It is throwing below error:
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: Right, I checked it. This should do the job:
`df = df.set_index('B').resample('1D').asfreq().reset_index()`
I'll update the post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but throwing IllegalMonthError: bad month number 18; must be 1-12
I tried ```df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'],format = '%Y-%w')
``` but  throws unconverted data error

Comment: Do you really have 18 in the month's position?

Comment: The date is weekly so it will have upto 52 as value for week's position

Comment: In this case `format = '%Y-%W'` should work (%w is the weekday from 0 to 6).